# var_dump says: STRING, echo says: Notice: Array to string conversion. <? PHP PDO

Tags: php, echo, var-dump

My code looks like the following:

```
try {
    $tagsel = $db->prepare('SELECT tag.name FROM tag LEFT JOIN '.TB_NAME.' ON tag.id = '.TB_NAME.'.tag WHERE '.TB_NAME.'.id =?');
    $tagsel->bindParam(1, $id);
    $tagsel->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't update database";
    exit;
}
$tagsel = $tagsel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($tagsel);
echo $tagsel;
```

The result is:

```
 string(6) "people"
 Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\blastbland\admin\inc\admin-   functions.php on line 171 Array
```

I was just wondering, how the heck is this possible? I need the $tagsel variable to be a string so I can compare with an other string later on, but surprisingly I found out, that it cannot be compared or echoed, but var_dump still tells me it's a string.
If anyone has an idea, I would appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: `echo $tagsel['name'];`

Comment: I've even tried that, unfortunately without an effect

Comment: there is no way that this could be happening, unless the code you are using isn't the same as the one you pasted here.

Comment: belive me or not, I'm using the code above. it was a simple copy/paste thing. it seemed nonsense for me, that's why I posted.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` - you're asking for an associative array here. If you just try to echo the result, PHP has to try to implicitly convert `$tagsel` to a string. You can see the contents of `$tagsel` by using `print_r` instead.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. print_r works, of course. My only problem is, that I can't use $tagsel as an array (like $tagsel['define'], and not even as a string. After all, using default fetch style solved the problem, so I can use $tagsel[0] as a string, but just seems a bit ugly to me. Thank you! :)

Comment: okay. I'm losing it. I thought it works, because the new result with default fetch style was: string(6) "people" [0]=> string(6) "people".
I can use echo $tagsel[0] only after var_dump($tagsel) to get the result "people". If I use just the echo and the exit the function I get nothing. Don't know, it seems pretty nonsense, I will try to look for mistakes in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not a real one.
You are running some other code, most likely something like this

```
var_dump($tagsel['name']);
echo $tagsel;
```

you have to pay more attention to the code you run and shouldn't ask other people to do it for you.

Comment: Well thanks. I wouldn't be asking this if it just wouldn't be so weird for me. Belive me, I'm paying attention, I've been stuck on this for a while now. I'm using the code above, you know, it's Ctrl+c then Ctrl+v

Comment: is that supposed to be a useful answer? seems more like preaching to me. but thank you for your time anyway, i guess.